# How to use variable field name in arcpy.SearchCursor?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop

I have code that says:

```
fld = fieldName 
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    x = row.fld
```

How do I use a variable for my field name in Python ArcGIS 10 on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row.getValue(field_name)`

See [Accessing data using cursors](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000.htm) in the help.

Comment: I just found that in some older code I wrote.  Thanks..but say I did not want to use the getValue method..is it possible using row.fld?

Comment: Nope. row.fld would look for a field named "fld".

Comment: Not to pester but I get that..so row is an object??..looking for a what and how could....ah nevermind..I guess that is why they put the getValue method in there..Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's a Row object. arcpy uses some voodoo to go between ArcObjects and Python objects, you can step through it in a Python debugger to see it in action.